# Hibernate 5 to 6 upgrade - how to continue using array of integers mapped to postgresql bytea columntype?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am attempting to upgrade an application originally on Spring boot 2.3.4 (with Hibernate 5) to Spring boot 3.1.4 (with Hibernate 6)

I am using PostGIS and previously had the dialect configured to
`org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisPG95Dialect`

I was previously on Java 11, now on Java 17.

This is apparently deprecated, so I followed the tooltip/feedback to switch over to
`org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

### Code (and data!) that originally worked

I have a persistent class with a member that has no JPA annotations at all:
`private int[] milestoneLevels;`

From what I read in other posts, it is in this case normal and expected that the resulting postgres data type is `bytea`.

These arrays are generally small, and I have no problem with any performance hit of the deserialisation. I also realise that I need to rely on the java serialisation to make sense of the column. I'm generally ok with it, and would just prefer to continue using it in the current form, instead of trying to migrate the column data (unless there is no other options).

I also have DDL updates turned on
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`

Here's a screenshot of what the data looks like in the database:

[image: Stored bytea values of the integer arrays]

### Problem

Compile is ok, but at runtime, I get following error:

```
2023-09-23T14:22:54.138+02:00  WARN 29469 --- [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists badge alter column milestone_levels set data type integer array" via JDBC [ERROR: column "milestone_levels" cannot be cast automatically to type integer[]
  Hint: You might need to specify "USING milestone_levels::integer[]".]
```

So for some reason, DDL tries to update the column type but fails to do so.
Is there any way (annotation?) I can use to tell Hibernate to keep on using the earlier bytea type, and keep the serialization and deserialisation in place?

I already tried turning DDL updates off, and then indeed this error disappears, but then there are other errors with SQL queries that try to touch this field. So it seems it's just unable to deserialise it back like it used to before.

Deeply appreciative for any guidance you might have on this subject.

Comment: Maybe it's not Hibernate 5 vs 6, but more of a Java 11 serialisation vs Java 17 serialisation issue.